# How to solve datetime comparing issue in python

Tags: python, datetime

My goal is to compare the datetime now with another datetime given to my program from a json.
After comparing the two datetimes , the result is different from the reality.

The timezone is `tz = pytz.timezone('Europe/Athens')` which is UTC+3

The json time initially is in string format and after handling I turn the format into datetime

`"start_time": "2020-08-11T20:13:00+03:00"`, the json data

```
start_time = data.get('start_time')

start_datetime = dateutil.parser.parse(start_time), #datetime format
```

Now after calling a function in order to check which datetime is bigger than the other, with

the information that the date now is:

```
2020-08-11 14:51:21.713511+03:00
```

and start_date is :

```
2020-08-11 13:00:00+03:00
```

the function returns `True` which is wrong since the start_datetime is not bigger than the datetime now.

Here is the function:

```
def check_start_datetime_bigger_than_now(start_datetime):
    tz = pytz.timezone('Europe/Athens')
    dts = start_datetime.replace(tzinfo=tz)
    dtnow = datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Europe/Athens'))

    print(dts)
    print(dtnow)



    #compare the datetimes
    if dts >= dtnow:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Can anyone help me on clarifying what's happening?

before the compare the print of datetimes is giving:

```
2020-08-11 20:13:00+01:35
2020-08-11 15:06:55.397784+03:00
```

Why the start date is giving `+01:35`

Comment: print both dates in the functions before comparing and see what is printed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `datetime.replace` to change the timezone of a `datetime` instance. It is not smart and cannot handle anything other than simple timezones like UTC. Use `datetime.astimezone` to convert an existing aware `datetime` to another timezone, or use `tz.localize` to add a timezone to a naïve `datetime` instance.

But really, if `start_datetime` already has a timezone, you do not need to change its timezone for it to be comparable to `dtnow`. Datetimes from two different timezones are still comparable. Only a mix of naïve and aware datetimes aren't comparable.

Comment: That was the issue. I had directly to compare startdate with the datetime now without defining any timezone. Now fixed . The improvement is : if start_datetime >= dtnow

Comment: The first sentence only holds true if you speak of time zones derived from pytz's `timezone`. It works fine if you use the same time zone model as `datetime` does, like `dateutil` at moment or `zoneinfo` will in Python 3.9. Minor thing: start_datetime as described by the OP only has a UTC offset - that's less information than a time zone.